# If I get a game from the Apple store, can I play it on other computers?

Tags: mac-appstore, copy-paste, games, drm

Let's say I buy a game from the app store from this computer.
Then I copy the game files to a external drive and go to a friend and copy them on his computer. Will my friend's computer play the game?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/can-i-copy-myself-an-app-purchased-through-the-mac-app-store-to-another-of-my?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purchased the game from the Mac App Store or iOS App Store, you can download it on other computers signed into your Apple ID.

On the Mac App store, click on the "Purchased" tab. If you need to sign in, sign in with your Apple ID. Then if you purchase an app, it will be attached to your Apple ID.

Then you will be able to redownload apps or games you have purchased with your Apple ID.

Comment: If I do that, will then my friend be able to play the game after I go home, or does she need my apple id and password every time she starts the game?

Comment: Once the Apple ID has been linked to the game and it has been downloaded, no Apple ID is needed for subsequent opening of the app. **Keep in mind you purchased the game for your personal use and it is not for redistribution. You may be violating the End User License Agreement by installing the app onto a user's device while the user did not pay for it**.

Comment: How can I remove that link from the friend's computer?

Comment: You would sign out of your Apple ID on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Oh so for the app to work, I'd need to always be signed in on the friend's computer?

Comment: No, once the app is installed your friend would always be able to use the application, even when you sign out of the Mac App Store.

Comment: What if my friend copies the game on a stick after I sign in, then gives it to one of her friends? Would it still require my sign in?

Comment: No, the app would not require your Apple ID.

Comment: So then the game can be played by anyone who receives the files. I think you're contradicting yourself in that case, because I don't see the point of having to sign in on the friend's computer if the game can be passed around without the need for subsequent sign-ins

Comment: To download the app on any computer, you would sign in on the Mac App Store with your Apple ID. Then you would download the app onto the computer and **you would be able to play it without having to be signed in** on the MAS. It could be distributed on a USB drive to any other computer independent of connecting to or being signed in on the MAS.

Comment: ok so then technically your answer is wrong and you can copy the game to another computer and use it. Only legally you are not allowed to.